# Deny access to Spring Cloud Config /config endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud

I have an embedded Spring Cloud Config server and client. I want to prevent all users from accessing the `https://host:port/config/*` endpoint. In my current situation anybody who performs an `HTTP GET` request to `https://host:port/config/application.yml` for instance, can see the whole application configuration. It is mentioned in the spring docs that I can prevent this using a username and password like so:

> 7.6 Security If you use HTTP Basic security on the server then clients just need to know the password (and username if it isn’t the default).
>   You can do that via the config server URI, or via separate username
>   and password properties, e.g.

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring: 
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://user:secret@myconfig.mycompany.com
```

or

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:   
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://myconfig.mycompany.com
      username: user
      password: secret
```

> The spring.cloud.config.password and spring.cloud.config.username
>   values override anything that is provided
>   in the URI.

My current `bootstrap.yml` is configured like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: 'MyApp'
  cloud:
      config:
        uri: 'http://localhost:${server.port}/config'
        enabled: true
        server:
            native:
                search-locations: '${config.location}'
            bootstrap: true
            prefix: '/config'
```

Is there a way I can achieve this without using a username and password?

Comment: The short answer is using spring-security like any normal application.

Comment: @spencergibb I am using spring-security and I am able to manage requests to anything under /api/**. However anything I do to try to block access to /config/** still returns the contents of my application.yml file after I perform a GET request. What do I need to change or add in my SecurityConfiguration.configure(HttpSecurtiy http) method to make this work?